# Apache Spark read datetime from SQL Server returns all 1/1/1900

Tags: sql-server, datetime, pyspark, azure-sql-database, mssql-jdbc

I am trying to read a table from AzureSQL database into Databricks using jdbc.
LoadDate **datetime** column is returned with all values set to **1900-01-01**T00:00:00.000+0000.

I thought that I should convert it in TSQL first to something else, so I created a view with cols like: Year(f.LoadDate) y. Event they were returned as zero.

Here is the code that I am running in Databricks notebook:

```
dbcHostName = "myserver.database.windows.net"
jdbcPort = "1433"
jdbcDatabase = "mydb"
connectionProperties = {
  "user":"myuser",
  "password":"mypwd",
  "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHostName,jdbcPort,jdbcDatabase)



pushdown_query = """(
    select top 100 * from dbo.vwExportTable
) t"""
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=pushdown_query, properties=connectionProperties)
display(df)
```

Here is code from view:

```
alter view vwExportTable
as
    select f.LoadDate, f.*,
    Year(f.LoadDate) y
    from edw.Fact f
where f.LoadDate > '2015-01-01'
;
```

There are even other cols that are defined also in SQL Server as datetime and I get values for them in Databricks.

**EDIT:**

```
CREATE TABLE [edw].[Fact](
    [BookingId] [int] NOT NULL,
    ...
    [BookingStartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    ...
    [LoadDate] [datetime] MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NOT NULL,

) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: can you provide your sample input and expected result?

Comment: Can you show the create table definition for the `edw.Fact` table - as text? Seems like `LoadDate` has something unusual about it that's confusing Spark.

Comment: It seems that you were right. There is this **Masked With** that does not exist on other cols.

Comment: LoadDate datetime column is returned with all values set to 1900-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000. Y col returns 0.

Comment: I guess, whoever did this decided to mask the values so, that we do not see when were things loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem was that LoadDate col is masked so that users cannot see the content. (And I didn't see that setting when I was checking data type in Object Browser).